# Inserting data in msaccess using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

I'm having a problem with inserting a data in ms access database using vb.net.

Below are my code and somehow I am getting an error "Number of query values is different with fields". Yes I tried using different codes and learning as much as I can but this is by far the best code i've got. Anyone can help me?

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.ConnectionString = con_str
            con.Open()
        End If
        oleDA.InsertCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        oleDA.InsertCommand.Connection = con
        oleDA.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblPlaylist VALUES (@Song,@Artist,@Album)"

        oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Song", txtboxSong.Text))
        oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Artist", txtboxArtist.Text))
        oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Album", txtboxAlbum.Text))
        oleDA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what fields does your table `tblPlaylist` have? it seems that Song,Artist and Album are not the only ones..

Comment: I have an ID field but it's set as primary key. When i try to put it on my calling fields, it prompts an error that value is not the same type with the ID field.

Comment: When you omit the columns in the INSERT clause you *have to* provide *all* values in correct order of the table. How do you fill the ID field? Is this an auto increment?

Comment: Yes sir, the ID field is auto increment.

Comment: In this case go with Erik´s answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to define both the columns you're inserting into and the values you're inserting into them. change this line:

```
    oleDA.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblPlaylist VALUES (@Song,@Artist,@Album)"
```

To this

```
    oleDA.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblPlaylist (Song, Artist, Album) VALUES (@Song,@Artist,@Album)"
```

Comment: Okay i'll try this. Thanks for the reply! Will get back to you later.